# Event Sourcing SQL Populate Parent and Child Table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Following up from question
[CQRS Read Model Design when Event Sourcing with a Parent-Child-GrandChild… relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523114/cqrs-read-model-design-when-event-sourcing-with-a-parent-child-grandchild-rel):

We utilize Event sourcing with SQL Server 2016 at Example: furniture company.
(1) We have a Parent and Child table. Say a FurnitureDescriptionTable, (Parent table- description of all furniture Items) and FurnitureOrders(Child - multiple customers orders, refers to FurnitureDescription table). Should the join column between these be Guid or Integer Identity in SQL?

(2) If Guid, who generates the Guid, API or SQL? any reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing what kind of type you need for for primary/foreign keys is a known problem in RDBMS world. Simple googling will help. But still:

Guids are usually done on the application side. This option is popular (since you are referring to CQRS) when command handlers can generate complete domain objects, including the identity. Otherwise, you need to have a unique identity generator, which might be non-trivial, but still feasible in some databases, like using Oracle sequences.

Numbers are usually chosen for database-generated ids. Then, new id will only be known when the row is inserted to a table. For event-sourcing scenario this is not an option, since you will only insert on the read side, but objects are created on the write side.

Comment: I think I simplied my question too much, I placed new question here as stackoverflow recommended, this time we have 100s of relations in a write event store, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289332/event-sourcing-and-sql-multiple-relational-tables