# Event Sourcing and SQL Server multiple relational tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

We use event sourcing with SQL Server 2016. We have total Customer Product Application, each is labelled by `CustomerId` and gets a single Guide line item in the event store. This is the primary identifier for write event store guids. The Product Applications comes with many different relational things, (which do not have guids but natural keys) each customer has Multiple Addresses, Accounts, Multiple purchase orders. The write event store will be mapped to a relational database tables any way we choose. In databases, we try to relate join by surrogate keys, instead of natural keys.

Can the surrogate keys be Guids, or can we utilize Integers (maybe Identity) for quicker Joins?

Remember the only primary identifier in Write Event store is a Guid from Customer ID app (big json blob with bunch of table column attributes we want to model), but the child relationships tables which can change any time in the read model, do not have child Guid in the Write event store.

Comment: The whole point of CQRS is to have the read model optimised for reading. Meaning - denormalised, no, or very little, joins, and so on. On top of that you can do what you want, just need to care that you will be updating the read model with events so aggregate id is sent through and kept on the read side.

Comment: That's interesting, I will keep the total Aggregate ID guid in all our 50 relational tables (in this case, we will place CustomerID guid into the 5-
 tables), Thanks, sad thing is books on data sql read models do not exist, so architecture is different from OLTP; also learned to remove unique and foreign constraints, as they are applied in Domain side

Comment: I think regarding the Inmon model, it allows flexibility to model and relate way we want, for example if I want to run a Distinct Sql function, that is already predone, vs running a distinct function on big wide multiple row Kimball model, however, I will ask our team to do both, thanks

Comment: Read models just represent DTOs. They do not require any modelling.

Comment: interesting,  I was reading this page, https://www.lavinski.me/generating-read-models-with-event-sourcing/ and  http://cqrs.nu/tutorial/cs/03-read-models,  you are saying read models don't require modeling, I will review this more

Comment: I mean flat data structures do not require extensive database modelling skills. They are just data bags. The projections of course can be rather extensive and might require deep thoughts to build properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use whatever you need in a particular `read model` implementation but you need to take into account that a `read model` should be rebuildable **at any time**. So, when a `read model` is re-builded it may use other surrogate IDs or you just implement it in such a way that every time it gets the same IDs (I'm referring to the `Autoincrement` feature).

P.S. why don't you try to denormalize your data? In `event sourcing` is common to avoid using join instead of making them faster in the `read model`.

Comment: @AppleBook89 Hi, I don't understand your question: "where did you get the source to denormalize the data"? From where I know that or what?

Comment: @AppleBook89 You can read the great tutorial from http://cqrs.nu/ Event-sourcing (and CQRS) works great with (Domain driven design )[https://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215]. There are a lot of other sources on the internet, too many in fact to be put here. Look also (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/tags/domain-driven-design/info]

Comment: @AppleBook89 I tend to agree with the (only) answer. However I don't fully understand your question/situation exactly.